# Discrepancy between the FontStyle enumeration and the available FontStyles of the CheckBox.Text FontStyles

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, fonts

The FontStyle enumeration is comprised of: Bold, Italic, Regular, Strikeout and Underline. Notwithstanding, when selecting a FontStyle of a CheckBox.Text font, the 
only available FontStyles are: Regular, Italic, Bold and BoldItalic.
1. Why does this discrepancy exist?
2. I have to iterate through the four above mentioned CheckBox.Text FontStyles: Regular, Italic, Bold and BoldItalic. In order to iterate and compare to an existing FontStyle, the FontStyle enumeration has to contain all the available CheckBox.Text FontStyles, including specifically BoldItalic.

Comment: The issue is not clear. How do you set the style for the check box text?

Comment: The Font selection dialog has two CheckBoxes, corresponding to `FontStyle.Underline` and `FontStyle.Strikeout`. If that is the issue.

Comment: Different fonts have different styles.  You should probably just check the HasFlag function on the style.

Comment: @ icebat:In the form I select the CheckBox and in the properties window, in the Font section I press the 3 ellipses and get the menu for the font style in the middle. In this menu for the font style, I select for instance Bold Italic. Later I want to find out programmatically what FontStyle this specific CheckBox.Text font has, so I have to iterate through the values of the FontStyle enumeration and compare with the  FontStyle  of the CheckBox.Text . The problem is that the FontStyle enumeration does not contain the value Bold Italic.

Comment: Jimi:Font selection dialog has for CheckBox.Text Font FontStyle has 4 values:  Bold, Italic, Regular and Bold Italic. The FontStyle enumeration has 5 values: Bold, Italic, Regular, Strikeout and Underline. The trouble is that the 2 groups of values do not coincide, so I cannot iterate through the FontStyle enumeration values and compare them to the CheckBox.Text Font FontStyle values.

Comment: @LarsTech:I am speaking about Times New Roman Font Family.

Comment: I don't think it matters.  Show your code.

Comment: You do know that these are flags and can be combined, right? The Font Dialog has, as already said, two CheckBoxes that can be used to set the FontStyle to `FontStyle.Strikeout | FontStyle.Underline`. You can add another style, if it's rrequired (e.g., `FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Strikeout | FontStyle.Underline`). As LarsTech already told you, you can use the Enum.HasFlag() method to verify if specific styles have been applied: (e.g., `checkBox1.Font.Style.HasFlag(FontStyle.Bold)`)